# Adding objects to sharedpreferences Android?

Tags: java, android, file, sharedpreferences

I am working on an android app and I am having trouble adding File objects to sharedPrefs. I have an add and getAll method, but nothing seems to be added to the sharedPref when I try to add to it..

```
public static ArrayList<File> getAll(Context context) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String str = pref.getString("files", null);
        if (str == null) return files;
        String[] shortcuts = str.split(",");
        for (String s : shortcuts) {
            if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()) continue;
            files.add(new File(s));
        }
        return files;
    }

    public static void add(Context context, File f) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        ArrayList<File> files = getAll(context);
        files.add(f);
        String toSet = "";
        for (File file : files) {
            toSet += file.getAbsolutePath() + ",";
        }
        pref.edit().putString("files", toSet).commit();
    }
```

Call to methods From Fragment.

```
Shortcuts.add(getActivity(), adapter.getItem(i));
Shortcuts.getAll(getActivity());
```

Comment: Add pref.commit() to save.

Comment: what do you mean? I already have pref.edit().putString("files", toSet).commit();

Comment: Where these methods are calling. What context you are passing? It seems the methods implementation are fine.

Comment: well I am calling them from a fragment, so I am passing in the getActivity() context, which in this case is the MainActivity...

Comment: Also, looking at the code, it looks like even when you are saving one File, a "," would be appended to it which would translates to *two* Strings when you split it in getAll(Context).